# How to call azure function with params

Tags: azure, azure-functions, cron-task

I am trying to use Azure function with to invoke the same function with different time and different param(url).
I didn't find any good example that shows how to pass some data. I want to pass link to function.
My code is:

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var request = require('request');

module.exports = function (context //need to get the url) {
```

and the function

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 0 */1 * * *"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Comment: Timer triggered functions use a simple CRON value to indicate how often they should run. They do not allow you to pass any other params besides the TimerInfo. How do you expect to be able to pass a URL? Perhaps you want an HTTP triggered function that will allow you to pass along a value in the request body?

Comment: yes. I am trying HTTP trigger,

Comment: Then why did you post a function.json for a Timer trigger instead of an HTTP trigger?

Comment: Because I thought that Json can be set with variable.i posted my function that should trigger the http ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility is if your parameters are stored somewhere in e.g. Azure Document DB (Cosmos).

You could still use a `TimerTrigger` to invoke the function, and include a DocumentDB input binding allowing you to query for the specific parameter values needed to execute the function.

Here's a C# example triggered by Timer, with a `DocumentDB` input binding. Note: I'm using the latest VS2017 Preview tooling for Azure functions.

```
[FunctionName("TimerTriggerCSharp")]
public static void Run(
   [TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log, 
   [DocumentDB("test-db-dev", "TestingCollection", SqlQuery = "select * from c where c.doc = \"Test\"")] IEnumerable<dynamic> incomingDocuments) 
 {..}
```

With the following binding json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    },
    {
      "type": "documentDB",
      "name": "incomingDocuments",
      "databaseName": "test-db-dev",
      "collectionName": "TestingCollection",
      "sqlQuery": "select * from c where c.docType = \"Test\"",
      "connection": "my-testing_DOCUMENTDB",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Comment: can see examples

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example  - we've been developing our functions in C# rather than node but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 2):

If your settings are relatively static (but you still don't want to hard code them), you may use app settings to store them, and then read e.g.

```
let url = process.env['MyUrl'];
```

If URL should be determined per request, you may use HTTP trigger and read the URL from query parameters:

```
let url = req.query.myurl;
```

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve with parameterized timer-triggered function.